# How do I set the title of a UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

This is what I did so far:

- I created a new view based iPhone application
- I added a navigation bar to the xib file

How do I set the title of this navigation bar?

- If I try `[self setTitle:@"Test"]` in `viewDidLoad`, the title of the navigation bar doesn't change, but rather it remains "Title".
- If I try `[[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"Test"]`, the title becomes empty.

How can I change this title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the view was pushed onto the navigation stack, then

```
[[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"Test"];
```

should exactly work. However, since you created the bar in the xib file, try making an `IBOutlet` for it, and then access the `title` property through the pointer.